# Porting UiBinder file in GWT for mobile

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I developed GWT desktop browser application , before working on porting the Application for webkit browsers I need to have following doubts clarified:

1. Is it possible to map mulitple UiBinder template with the same View class?
2. Are the widgets consistent in look and feel for Desktop as well as webkit(mobile) browsers?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at the mobilewebapp example which comes with the GWT SDK. There you can see, how an app can serve different views depending on the device by using deferred binding.
2. Using the first approach, you have different views for each device. So, you are free to choose different widgets for different platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I want to share one the method that I tried, First of all instead of mapping view to viewimpl you can bind it to viewprovider, and then based on user-agent values you can return the appropriate instance to bind to.I implemented this in sample application and its working fine as of now.